# Paypal smart button server side php

Tags: php, paypal, payment

i’m new to payment gateways in general im not sure what im doing so what im trying to do is check if the client changed the amount of money to pay on the server side this is the smart button script

```
    <div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable- 
   funding=venmo&currency=USD" 
    data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
   <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',

        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":50}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

As you can see client can change the "value":50 to any amount how can i prevent this i tried searching alot and i didn’t find good videos on how to secure it

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a client-side JS SDK integration. To have control over order creation and captures, you need to perform those operations from a server.

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

If you need to transfer any data from the client to the server, add a `body` object to the fetch parameters. This will become JSON input to your server route (look up how to read JSON input in PHP--you do *not* use $_POST for this, that is for form encoded inputs).

Your server verifies/controls the amount of the order creation in the create route, and verifies successful payment for the correct amount in the capture route, before propagating the response back to the client JS.

Comment: So just to make sure that i got it right, so createOrder will fetch the data from the server where it will return the price / other infortmation and the onApprove is when the user actually paid it will also send data to the server and perform some actions?

Comment: No, createOrder will tell the server to call the PayPal API to create the order. The server will return the id. onApprove will tell the server that the order has been approved, so that it can call the PayPal API to capture it. The server will do so, record the details on success, and forward the response to the client.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help i just finished it i didnt use the server API since for some reason the paypal php api docs are down im not sure why.
but thank you so much!

Comment: There are no PHP-specific docs. There is https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK you can use if you want, and the Orders API reference https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body ; you need to use the API if you want a reliable integration.

Comment: Yep i have finished it thank you so much for that and everything works just a small last question how can i change from sandbox to Live? im trying to search in the config but i didnt find golive or sandbox true/false

Comment: The JS SDK takes a live client ID. The server SDK takes a live client ID and secret as well as some parameter telling it that it's the live environment.